# How to manually hookup a jaydata model to a (non-O-Data) restful service

Tags: jaydata

I like all the features that JayData provides.  I am wondering for when I occasionally have a non-O-Data restful service if there is a way to manually hookup CRUD ops to my existing jaydata entity definitions so that I can take advantage of all the kendoui/knockout goodness that comes with this.

Is there any example where a jaydata entity definition is manually hooked up to restful service url kind of like the jquery method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Our webapi provider is what your are after. Do not worry about its name, webapi is a microsoft framework for rest apis, hence the name, but it should work with other restful endpoints, php, java, ruby, etc. Of course it is only good for crud, as filtering, paging, ordering and projection is only standardized in odata. Also, for paging length() is needed, so that must be implemented on the server side, too.
Give it a try and tell us about your experience, good or bad, we're to help you.
Or consider using oData, JayData can act as an odata endpoint on the server side, we also have hosted odata service.

Comment: After reading your answer I googled "jaydata webapi" and stumbled upon: http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-use-jaydata-with-asp.net-web-api---i

It's nice to know that you guys went to the lengths of providing automatic mapping to the default webapi scaffolding of asp.net web.api.

This is not a showstopper for me, but it would be nice if at a slightly lower level the restful url paths would be configurable so that, given a certain entity schema (we kind of have to agree on a schema at the minimum), one could do the put/post/delete/gets to different paths

Comment: I work for JayData and I really like it, still I think that JayData is not a panacea. To attach a rest service to KendoUI for CRUD can be done easily without JayData. See this for example: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/datasource-rest-integration-examples.aspx  JayData can come handy for oData (it just works) or when you need more than just CRUD or when you work with local datasources.

Comment: There is huge value in having one common client side viewmodel that "speaks" all the different ui binding protocols, like kendoui or knockout, etc... I realize these can be easily coded one by one but, to me, a major value of jaydata would be this universal "glue"ness.  Therefore, being able to bind this glue manually to already existing restful services once centrally would be going the extra mile to allow the client side flexibility to extend to server side flexibility (within reason).  One example would be to allow the verbs (actions) for the CRUD operations to be specified...